# Prove that a polynomial of odd degree has a real root $(f(x)<0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that a polynomial of odd degree has a real root.

Let $f(x)=x^d + a_{d-1}x^{d-1} + ... + a_1x+a_0$.

Find $x$ such that $f(x)<0$.

Lecture note: Suppose $|x|$ is large, so 
$$|x|>|a_{d-1}|+|a_{d-2}|+...+|a_1|+|a_0|.$$
Then, for $|x|>1$

$$|x^d|=|x||x^{d-1}|>(|a_{d-1}|+...+|a_0|)|x^{d-1}|$$

$$=|a_{d-1}x^{d-1}|+...+|a_0x^{d-1}|$$

$$>|a_{d-1}x^{d-1}|+...+|a_0|$$

$$>|a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+...+a_0|$$

If $x<0, |x|=-x. $Then,

$$x<-(|a_{d-1}|+...+|a_0|).$$

Then, we find $x$ such that  $f(x)<0$.

I am a little bit confused about the last part of this proof. Could you show me more steps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the intermediate value theorem: find where the polynomial is positive,  and find another spot where it is negative. Then there must exist a zero of the function.

Here is the inequality:

$$|x^d| > |a_{d-1}x^{d−1}+...+a_0|$$

If $x$ is negative, it implies that

$$f(x) = x^d + a_{d-1}x^{d−1}+...+a_0 < x^d + |a_{d-1}x^{d−1}+...+a_0| < 0$$

Comment: My question is how to find the case for $f(x)<0$.

Comment: What step specifically do you not understand?

Comment: I understand up to $x<-(|a_{d-1}|+...+|a_0|)$, but don't know why this result implies $f(x)<0$. So, I want to know the steps between these.